# AWS Lambda node express web application with push notifications

Tags: node.js, express, aws-lambda

I have a simple node.js express web application, with two routes a GET - serves an HTML page with results from db - and POST - saves records to DynamoDB (via postman or curl). This is deployed on AWS Lambda (cost savings, simplicity). When a POST occurs I need to update all web clients, to surface the newly saved records. Right now I do it with a meta tag in the html page, refreshing the page every minute or so. Was wondering if there is another way to do this without major architectural changes.

Comment: You should edit your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that those answering this question have something work with. Also let us know what you've tried, what went wrong and anything else you can think of that would help us help you.

Comment: I'm not necessarily looking for code, more like direction. I have a workaround that I did mention -- refreshing the page every minute. I tried googling but since it's a lambda, the ties with client are severed after a while, so when a db insert happens not sure how to notify web clients. Also unsuccessfully tried websockets.